# Flattening PDF without /AcroForm fields with /Annot Widget

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm struggling with flattening using iTextSharp 5.5.10.  This code represent a variety of efforts to flatten this PDF following code found on SO and Google searches.

```cs
void Process()
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(mInFileName);
    // 1 type of fields
    AcroFields formFields = reader.AcroFields;
    int countAcroFields = formFields.Fields.Count;
    // 2 another type of fields
    PRAcroForm form = reader.AcroForm;
    List<PRAcroForm.FieldInformation> fieldList = form.Fields;
    // 3 i think this is the same as 2
    PdfDictionary acroForm = reader.Catalog.GetAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
    PdfArray acroFields = (PdfArray)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(acroForm.Get(PdfName.FIELDS), acroForm);
    // 4 another type of fields
    XfaForm xfaForm = formFields.Xfa;
    bool flatten = false;

    if (countAcroFields > 0)
    {
        //No fields found
    }
    else if (fieldList.Count > 0)
    {
        //No fields found
    }
    else if (xfaForm.XfaPresent == true)
    {
        //No xfaForms found
        ReadXfa(reader);
    }
    else
    {
        // Yes, there are annotations and this code extracts them but does NOT flatten them
        PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(1);
        PdfArray annotsArray = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
        if ( annotsArray == null)
            return;
        else
        {
            List<string> namedFieldToFlatten = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in annotsArray)
            {
                var annot = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(item);

                var type = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annot.Get(PdfName.TYPE)).ToString(); //Expecting be /Annot
                var subtype = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annot.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)).ToString(); //Expecting be /Widget
                var fieldType = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annot.Get(PdfName.FT)).ToString(); //Expecting be /Tx

                if (annot.Get(PdfName.TYPE).Equals(PdfName.ANNOT) &&
                    annot.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.WIDGET))
                {
                    if (annot.Get(PdfName.FT).Equals(PdfName.TX))
                    {
                        flatten = true;
                        var textLabel = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annot.Get(PdfName.T)).ToString(); //Name of textbox field
                        namedFieldToFlatten.Add(textLabel);
                        var fieldValue = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annot.Get(PdfName.V)).ToString(); //Value of textbox
                        Console.WriteLine($"Found Label={textLabel} Value={fieldValue}");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (flatten == true)
            {
                // Flatten the PDF [11/9/2016 15:10:06]
                string foldername = Path.GetDirectoryName(mInFileName);
                string basename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(mInFileName);
                string outName = $"{foldername}\\{basename}_flat.pdf";
                using (var fStream = new FileStream(outName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    //This totally removes the fields instead of flattening them
                    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fStream) { FormFlattening = true, FreeTextFlattening = true, AnnotationFlattening = true };
                    var stamperForm = stamper.AcroFields;
                    stamperForm.GenerateAppearances = true;
                    foreach (var item in namedFieldToFlatten)
                    {
                        stamper.PartialFormFlattening(item);
                    }
                    stamper.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips on how to turn the "fields" into text as flatten does in Acrobat?

[This](https://app.box.com/s/olb3c8wffieyoei3ubs3yppzj9ktex2g) is the PDF I'm trying to flatten.

[This](https://app.box.com/s/zfk41o10qo18a8tfyywe8n53w1o566va) is what the output of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your form is broken. It indeed has `/Annots`, and those annotations are *widget annotations* that also have entries that are meant to be entries in a *field dictionary*, but there is no form in the PDF. Or rather: there is a form, but the `/Fields` array is empty.

As the `/Fields` array is empty, there are no fields to flatten. The widget annotations are removed and you don't see anything. This is not an iText bug: you need to fix the form before filling it out.

In Java, you'd fix the form like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfDictionary root = reader.getCatalog();
PdfDictionary form = root.getAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
PdfArray fields = form.getAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);

PdfDictionary page;
PdfArray annots;
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    page = reader.getPageN(i);
    annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    for (int j = 0; j < annots.size(); j++) {
        fields.add(annots.getAsIndirectObject(j));
    }
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

It should be fairly easy to port this to C#. I'm not a C# developer, but this is an (untested) attempt at making a port:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfDictionary root = reader.Catalog;
PdfDictionary form = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
PdfArray fields = form.GetAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);
PdfDictionary page;
PdfArray annots;
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++) {
    page = reader.GetPageN(i);
    annots = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    for (int j = 0; j < annots.Size; j++) {
        fields.Add(annots.GetAsIndirectObject(j));
    }
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Once you've fixed the form like this, you'll be able to flatten it correctly.

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  This worked.  If I may ask a followup question, Is there an easy way to detect "broken" forms like this?  Or do I just need to examine the output of my existing code to check for 0 fields with /Widgets?

Comment: Yes, no /AcroForm object or an empty /Fields array while there are /Annots of type /Widget associated with pages indicates that the form wasn't created correctly.